# Ng-grid how to save the value of the cell?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have to make an invoice application, and I have to use ng-grid.

But I cannot figure out how to take the value that the user will insert into the cell, and use it.

```
    $scope.myData = [{},{},{}]; /*tre row di default*/
    $scope.gridOptions = { 

      data: 'myData', 
      enableCellSelection: true,
      enableCellEdit: true,
      enableRowSelection: false,
      columnDefs: [{field: 'Numero', displayName: 'Numero', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field:'Descrizione', displayName:'Descrizione'},
      {field: 'CostoUnitario', displayName: 'Costo Unitario', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'Qta', displayName: 'Qta', enableCellEdit: true},
      {field: 'Totale', displayName: 'Totale', enableCellEdit: false},]
    };
 $scope.addRow = function() {
      $scope.myData.push({});
    };
```

I really don't know how to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using row.entity object..

On html side, define your input with ng-model="exapmle" as you probably did..
On angular side, get your textbox value with row.entity.example

An example which i did recently.. Look at last column def column..

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'accounts',
    multiSelect: false,
    showFilter: false,
    showColumnMenu: false,
    showSelectionCheckbox: false,
    showGroupPanel: false,
    showMenu:false,
    showFooter: false,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [                   
         {field: 'username', displayName: 'Username', width:180},
         {field: 'email', displayName: 'Email', width:250},
         {field: 'role.displayTxt', displayName: 'Role', width:120},
         {field: 'active', displayName: 'Active', width:80},
         {field: '', displayName: ' ', width: 50, 
             cellTemplate: '<div class="grid-action-cell">' + 
             '<a class="btn-link" type="button" title="Edit" ng-href="#/accounts/{{row.entity.username}}">' + 
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="left:8px; top:8px;"></i>' +
             '</a>' +
             '</div>'
         }, 
        ]
};
```

Comment: But on html, I dont' have any input, that's the problem... because if I had input type, I could simply put the ng-model, and call it into the controller.But here I just have the ng-grid slappet on the html... TT_TT
Anyway, thank you a lot for the answer, I'll try to use it :D

Comment: @Mariagrazia.B what do you have then :) lets try that way, give us more info

Comment: I'm soooo new to angular, so, maybe I'm making terrible mistakes.
On html I've wrote this:

  <div class="tabella_fattura">
   
      <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" value={{totaleSingolo()}}> <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="removeItem($index)"/></div>
      
  </div>

Comment: @Mariagrazia.B Ok, dont write your input field in your ng-grid div. You have to code this dynamic html element in your controller with $scope.gridOptions dynamically. See my answer, in tne last column i dynamically added a <a> element and defined ng-href.. So you should do the same thing, write an input field dynamically and define ng-model for this and probably a remove button which you add ng-click same way

Comment: Thank you very much! You were so kind!